# Django Python Shell

Tags: python, django

How do I enter the Django Shell? I am not seeing clear instructions on how to achieve this.

Comment: In the views most of the time yes.

Comment: You should follow the tutorial, where all that is explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run that code interactively in the dev shell.

```
python manage.py shell
```

For future reference, though: all you need to do to make a plain `.py` file "Django compatible" is that you set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable before importing any Django stuff:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproj.settings")
from myapp.models import Stuff
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. As much as I read the documentation, the import os comment did not come up until much later.